# Clears form POST entry when i press back (-1)

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a 2 page form system,The first page form is 'post'ing some variable by submitting and 2nd page uses the post variable as input and inserting in to mysql

Now my problem is when one press browser back button from second page, he is losing all his first page form entries....!

How can i retain the first form entris when one backs from second form

```
<table align='center'>
<form method='post' action='addcd.php'>
  <tr>
    <td><div class='tabdata' align="right">Well No: </div></td>  
    <td ><input type="text" name="no" autocomplete="off" required="required" class='tfield' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class='tabdata' align="right">Well Name</td>  
    <td ><input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required="required" class='tfield'/></td>
    <td width="40%" align="left"><div class='tfield' id="status"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class='tabdata' align="right">No of Logs in CD</td> 
    <td><input type='number' name='nologs' autocomplete="off" min="1" max="5" required="required" class='tfield'/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>         
  <tr>
    <td colspan='12' align='center'><input type='submit' value='ADD A CD' name='submit' class='button'/></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

This the code of addcd.php

```
   <table align="center">
   <?php
  $wno = $_POST['no'];
  $wname = $_POST['name'];  
  ?>
    <form method='post' action='' name="cdplus">
        <tr>    
            <td colspan='2' align="center"><input type='text' name='no' class='tfield' value="<?php echo$wno?>" readonly /></td>
            <td colspan='3' align="center"><input type='text' name='name' class='tfield' value="<?php echo$wname?>" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='tabd'>Curve Status</th>
            <th class='tabd'>Log</th>
            <th class='tabd'>Top Depth</th>
            <th class='tabd'>Bottom Depth</th>
            <th class='tabd'>Date of Log</th>
        </tr>   
 <?php 
        $number=$_POST['nologs'];
        for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){
  ?>            
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5" align="center" class='tabdata'>File No: <?php echo$i?></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name='status[]' type='text' required="required" placeholder="Curve Status" autocomplete="off" class='tabdata'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name='logs[]' type='text' required="required" placeholder="Logs" autocomplete="off" class='tabdata'>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type='number' required="required" name='bottom[]' placeholder="Bottom Depth" class='tabdata'>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type='number' required="required" name='top[]' placeholder="Top Depth" class='tabdata'>
            </td>

            <td><input type='text' required="required" name='date[]' placeholder="Date of Logging" class="tabd" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
  <?php } ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='5' align='center'><input type='submit' value='Save' name='submit' class='button'/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
```

Comment: post your code of addcd.php

Comment: simple: use sessions

Comment: @ Fred -ii-: can i destroy part of session variables after executing some query..?

Comment: @user3521051 Yes..you can

Comment: @ affaz: can you please give an example for destroying stored value in a session variable

Comment: unset($_SESSION['var']);
$_SESSION['var']=" "; // using because, it destroy the variable itself, not the data stored in the variable..Thanks everybody for giving hints, now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You just must not press back.

It shouldnt be intended to click the back-button when you dont want to repeat the input process.

You could however save the data the user entered in the second page by creating a temporary text-file that contains the data the user entered, and then read them in again on the first page.

You could make a if-statement that checks if such a file exists and if it could read the data in from that file back into the input.

If no file exists, he would make the input again.